# Add rows of comboboxes to datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to create a DataGrid that will have one row be the column headers, and then 10 more rows, filled with comboboxes for each column. For instance:

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Name="dataGrid1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Products" 
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ProductName}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ProductNamesList, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ProductNamesList, 
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Amount" />

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Units" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Now, I would need 10 rows of 3 comboboxes. I've tried to Google it, but my Google-Fu is failing me, as what I've found tells me to bind the rows to a list. Is what I want possible? Or should I just find another way?

**EDIT 1**

What I'd meant to ask, is once I have this, how can I populate 10 rows of 3 comboboxes? Each column will have the same items in the box.

**EDIT 2**

I edited to show that I've added Jim's code. However, if I create a `ProductNamesList`, and fill it with 10 items, and bind it to my column, I get 10 rows of empty boxes.

**EDIT 3**

Here's the `List<string>`:

```
        var ProductNamesList = new List<string>();
        var test1 = "test1";
        var test2 = "test2";
        var test3 = "test3";
        var test4 = "test4";
        var test5 = "test5";
        var test6 = "test6";
        var test7 = "test7";
        var test8 = "test8";
        var test9 = "test9";
        var test10 = "test10";

        ProductNamesList.Add(test1);
        ProductNamesList.Add(test2);
        ProductNamesList.Add(test3);
        ProductNamesList.Add(test4);
        ProductNamesList.Add(test5);
        ProductNamesList.Add(test6);
        ProductNamesList.Add(test7);
        ProductNamesList.Add(test8);
        ProductNamesList.Add(test9);
        ProductNamesList.Add(test10);

        grid1.ItemsSource = ProductNamesList;
```

Comment: You know of [DataGridComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx)?

Comment: @LPL: Thanks. I did know about that, and I meant to change the item when I copy/pasted my code from another datagrid. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Are you using a particular design pattern or is this going to use code behind? If so my next question is why comboboxes? What will the options be for the Amount column for example? What you are asking is possible yes but a little more info about the problem would be useful

Comment: @Kazuo: There's no particular pattern, and it doesn't matter if this happens in the xaml or code behind. It's comboboxes because that's what my boss wants. For `Amount`, it can range from 1 to 100. `Units` would be varying measurements types, and `Product` would be the product name.

Comment: Can you show the code where you "...create a ProductNamesList, and fill it with 10 items..."

Comment: @Jim: Edited to show requested code.

Comment: See my updated answer. The way the setter property works in this case is to look for a property of the window `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}` named `ProductNamesList`. This can be changed since you didn't specify where the lists were coming from

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind the combobox column's element and editing styles to your list. This example binds it to a list in the window.cs file.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> ProductNamesList { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ProductNamesList = new List<string>();

        ProductNamesList.Add("Hamburger");
        ProductNamesList.Add("Uranium");
        ProductNamesList.Add("Toothbrush");
    }
}

<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Products" 
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ProductName}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ProductNamesList, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ProductNamesList, 
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Using this code, if I create a list of 10 items, and bind it, I get 10 rows of empty comboboxes.

Comment: Update your question with more code and maybe we can troubleshoot it.